# SQLAlchemy: Separation of table classes by different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

I will try to explain in order so that my question is clear.
The simplified code executed according to the lesson:

```
engine = create_engine(...)
session = (...)
Base = declarative_base()

class <someTable>(Base):
    ...

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

And in this case, everything works as it should. A table in the database is being created.
Next I want to split a lot of *(Base)* into by different files located in the same folder "schemas". Now, after launching the application, tables are not created, because there is no explicit definition of "class (Base)" before "create_all".
I thought that if import "Base" in a separate file in which a specific "class (Base)" is registered, then this will be enough.
The first thing that comes to mind is to put an "if" condition before each CRUD operation - if the table does not exist, then "create_all".
The first thing that comes to mind is to put an "if" condition before each CRUD operation - if the table does not exist, then "create_all".

The file structure of the project looks something like this:

```
|project
|
|-|utils
| |-db_api
| |-|db_api
|   |-|schemas
|     |-__init__.py
|     |-<someTable_1>.py #Contains "class <someTable_1>(Base)"
|     |-<someTable_2>.py
|   |-__init__.py
|   |-session.py #there session, Base, and create_all
|   |-<some_db_commands>.py
| |-__init__.py
| |-<some_bot_funcs>.py
|-main.py
```

This is a simple training telegram bot that uses the "/start" command to create a table in postgres and writes the user id there.
Can I keep a similar file structure by achieving SQLAlchemy operability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each model class must be read by the interpreter before `create_all` is called, otherwise they will not be in the metadata and so will not be created. So what you need to do is:

1. Define `Base` in a module.
2. All the files that declare model classes must import the module that defines `Base`, and *use that `Base` as their superclass*.
3. In (say) `main.py`, import `Base` and all the model classes (so that they are read by the interpreter) and then do `Base.metadata.create_all()`.

You may be able to adjust the above steps a little, but understand that generally you won't be able to declare `Base` and do `create_all()` in the same file without creating circular dependencies

Comment: Hello, I understand that the model should get into "metadata", it's just that even in debugging mode I couldn't put together a complete picture of why in my case they don't get there.
I have already completed the steps 1 and 2 described by you. And it's really very easy to get into cyclical import. I tried to insert the "create_all" function in different places of the program, but everything was unsuccessful.
Regarding the third point, I feel that this should solve the problem, but I still don't understand why it doesn't help in my case. In my example with the command "/start":(next comment)

Comment: I came to this solution - create in the file "main.py " the "on_startup" function. In this function, "metadata.create_all()" will be called.
The small question remains, will this be a good practice for such a solution to the structure and design?
Thank you in advance for the answer, you helped me a lot by giving me the right idea.

Comment: `on_startup` sounds like the right place to call `create_all()`.